# "Made" meaning "created"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Is the use of the verb "to make" make acceptable in the sentence below? Does it work with the meaning of "create"?

*Some nights she used to sit for hours on her doorstep, looking up at the sky and wondering why were each of of those stars made for.*

Comment: What aspect of the word "make" are you uncertain about?

Comment: what each of those stars was made for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that "to make" and "to create" mean the same thing. However, the grammar at the end of your sentence sounds a bit strange to me. I (native English speaker from the US), would say:

> Some nights she used to sit for hours on her doorstep, looking up at the sky and wondering why each of the stars were made.

Or you could say

> Some nights she used to sit for hours on her doorstep, looking up at the sky and wondering what each of the stars were made for.

In English, the phrase "[object] are made for [purpose]" or "[object] are created for [purpose]" can be combined with the word "what" but not with the word "why." This is because there is an implied noun. It could be rephrased as "what is the purpose of the stars?" but not "why is the purpose of the stars?"